# Thread Parameters change during thread execution - why?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parameter-passing, threadstatic

So I have a method that gets a `Dictionary` of `List<myObj>`, then cycles through the keys of the dictionary and passes each `List<myObj>` to a separate thread.

Here is some Code / Psuedo-Code:

```
public static void ProcessEntries()
{
    Dictionary<string, List<myObj>> myDictionary = GetDictionary();

    foreach(string key in myDictionary.keys)
    {
        List<myObj> myList = myDictionary[key];

        Thread myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
        {
            ProcessList(myList);
        }    
    }
}

public static void ProcessList(List<myObj> myList)
{
    // Process entries
    // read-only operations on myList
}
```

The problem is that during execution of `ProcessList` the `myList` parameter simply changes.

I have looped through the list before kicking of the thread, and then immediately inside the thread, and I've found the results to be different.

I have since solved the problem (I think!) by making the `Dictionary` variable global. Using the `[ThreadStatic]` property is next on the list of possible fixes.

What I really want to know is why does the `myList` object changes inside `ProcessList()` presumably when the `myList` object is re-assigned in `ProcessEntries()`?  Are these not two different `Lists`?  If all parameter passing is by value by default, why does the `ProcessList()` function not have a local copy of `myList`? (does it?)

Is there a way to specify that you want to pass a parameter to a thread and not have it be altered by the parent thread or other threads during execution? (This would be similar to the `[ThreadSafe]` attribute for global variables)

Comment: Are you sure that your code/psuedocode is correct and complete? From what I can see, while your assumptions about what happens are wrong, it looks like the code should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your pseudo-code isn't actually an accurate reflection of your real code. I suspect your *real* code looks like this:

```
foreach(var pair in myDictionary)
{
    Thread myThread = new Thread(delegate() {
        ProcessList(pair.Value);
    });
    myThread.Start();
}
```

If that's the case, the problem is that the `pair` variable is being captured - so by the time your thread starts, it may be referring to a different key/value pair.

The way to fix it is to make the code precisely more like your pseudo-code:

```
foreach(var pair in myDictionary)
{
    // You'll get a new list variable on each iteration
    var list = pair.Value;
    Thread myThread = new Thread(delegate() {
        ProcessList(list);
    });
    myThread.Start();
}
```

See [Eric Lippert's blog post on this](https://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/) for more information.

If this isn't what's going wrong, please give a *real* example rather than pseudo-code. A [short but complete example demonstrating the problem](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/complete.html) would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a *reference* by value in that case, so if you modify it somewhere it will be different everywhwere.

Answer (score 1):

Also be sure that other threads don't affect the thread you're trying to use. be sure to use locks and monitors... Had some issues with that just few weeks ago..